# Is there a limit to the size of objects sent via a client to a SOAP web service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans

With Netbeans I have created a SOAP web service and its corresponding web service client. The client can call a method that takes a List as argument.  Is there a limit to the size of this object, above which time outs or other things will break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theoretical maximum a SOAP message can be is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes. Hence, you should rather worry about how much memory is available to your service, and the time taken to process.

Comment: that's a lot of bytes! math is hard - so to make it easy, that's roughly 8.3819 GB's